# Query regarding Telerik Radgrid

Tags: asp.net

I am using Telerik Radgrid for my aspx page. I have uploaded the screenshot here. The problem here is that, if there are no items in the radgrid, the message 'No records to display' should expand to the end of the grid. If you see the screenshot, the message box within the grid ends before the grid actually ends. I have uploaded the code that I have used. Is there any way out?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ManageUsers.aspx.cs" Inherits="Settings_ManageUsers" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style002.css">

</head>

<body>
   <h2 class="Boldheader" style="color: #4173be; font-size: x-large">Manage Users</h2>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" CssClass="formEditBtn" Text="Add User" />
    <telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1"></telerik:RadScriptManager>

    <telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">   
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pageLoad(sender, eventArgs) {
            if (!eventArgs.get_isPartialLoad()) {
                $find("<%= radAjax.ClientID %>").ajaxRequest("InitialPageLoad");
            }
        }
        function OnClientClose(oWnd, args) {
            var radMgr = $find("<%=radAjax.ClientID %>");
            radMgr.ajaxRequest("Rebind");
        }
    </script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        /*function openWin(id) {
        if (id != "") {
        var oWnd = radopen("EditUser.aspx?id=" + id, "_self");
        }
        }*/

        function openWin(id) {
            window.open("EditUser.aspx?id=" + id, "_self");
        }

        //]]>
    </script>
    </telerik:RadCodeBlock> 

    <telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" ShowContentDuringLoad="false"  VisibleStatusbar="false"
        ReloadOnShow="true" runat="server" OnClientPageLoad="OnClientClose">
        <Windows>
            <telerik:RadWindow ID="EditWindow" Behaviors="Reload" runat="server"
                NavigateUrl="EditUser.aspx" VisibleTitlebar="false" >
            </telerik:RadWindow>
        </Windows>
    </telerik:RadWindowManager>

    <telerik:RadAjaxManager runat="server" ID="radAjax" OnAjaxRequest="AjaxManager_AjaxRequest" DefaultLoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" >
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="radAjax">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="grdUsers" UpdatePanelRenderMode="Inline" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>

    <telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="grdUsers" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnItemDataBound="grdUsers_ItemDataBound"
     OnNeedDataSource="grdUsers_NeedDataSource" 
        OnItemCommand="grdUsers_ItemCommand" GridLines="Both" Width="288px" 
        style="margin-right: 13px">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="SummaryTableHdrRow" Font-Bold="true" />
    <ItemStyle CssClass="SummaryTableDataRow" />
    <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="SummaryTableDataRow" />
    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="UserId" Width="100%">
    <Columns>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="UserName" HeaderText="User Name" ></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridButtonColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" CommandName="delete" ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to delete this user? (If yes, press OK, else cancel)"
         ImageUrl="../images/delx.gif" ItemStyle-Width="25px" HeaderStyle-Width="25px"></telerik:GridButtonColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="UserId" Visible="false"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
    <ClientSettings>
    <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" UseStaticHeaders="true" />
    </ClientSettings>
    </telerik:RadGrid>

    <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" Transparency="30" Height="100%" Width="75px" BackgroundPosition="Center">
    <table style="height:100%;width: 100%;" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" align="center" valign="middle">
        <img src="../images/loading.gif" s![enter image description here][1]tyle="border:0;"  />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>

    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblError" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Telerik.Web.UI;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.Data;

public partial class Settings_ManageUsers : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (Security.EnforceSecurity())
        //    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("SQLServerCompactEditionUnderWebHosting", true);



    }
    protected void grdUsers_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)

    {
        BindData();
    }
    private void BindData()
    {
        try
        {
            string connectString = "Data Source=" + Server.MapPath(".") + "\\Security.sdf";
            using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connectString))
            {
                using (SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "select * ";
                    cmd.CommandText += "from Users order by UserName";
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    grdUsers.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
        }

    }
    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("EditUser.aspx?id=0");
    }
    protected void grdUsers_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "delete")
        {
            try
            {
                GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
                string userId = item["UserId"].Text;
                string connectString = "Data Source=" + Server.MapPath(".") + "\\Security.sdf";
                using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connectString))
                {
                    using (SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "delete ";
                        cmd.CommandText += "from Users ";
                        cmd.CommandText += "where UserId = @UserId";
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@UserId", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = userId;
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
                grdUsers.Rebind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblError.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    protected void grdUsers_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            string value = e.Item.Cells[2].Text;
            HyperLink eLink = new HyperLink();
            eLink.NavigateUrl = "javascript: void 0";
            eLink.Attributes.Add("onclick", "openWin('" + e.Item.Cells[4].Text + "');");
            eLink.Text = value;
            e.Item.Cells[2].Controls.Clear();
            e.Item.Cells[2].Controls.Add(eLink);

        }
    }
    protected void AjaxManager_AjaxRequest(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        grdUsers.Rebind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what the NoRecordsTemplate is for:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server">
    <MasterTableView ...>
         <Columns>
             ...
         </Columns>
         <NoRecordsTemplate>
              <!-- TEMPLATE FOR WHEN THERE ARE NO RECORDS -->
         </NoRecordsTemplate>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```